# Unable to install apk to android emulator via adb，Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 in Android studio Performing Streamed Install

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Appears when I run in Android Studio
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAg6b.png)

When I use cmd to install a random apk that I downloaded, it takes a long time to 'Performing Streamed Install'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2ys3.png)

My adb version is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhrCt.png)
I can be sure that my Android emulator has enough memory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY7Ul.png)

When I tried to change an Android emulator, I got other errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhZQm.png)
I tried restarting my computer many times and it didn't work
When I try to install it on my real phone, it still can't be installed, but the running window shows my activity on the phone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1St8.png)

Can you help me?